# about the order of spring bean initialing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inversion-of-control

I have a custom spring-boot starter project which is used by rest controller, the auto configuration class is used for creating several(according to config value in application.yml) Storage Context instance as spring singleton, so I have to create them dynamically in setBeanFactory method of BeanFactoryAware by :

```
@Import(StorageContextProperties.class)
public class StorageAutoConfiguration implements BeanFactoryAware {

      ......
        
      @Override
      public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory factory) throws BeansException {

         ......

         StorageContextProperties config = beanFactory.getBean(StorageContextProperties.class);

         config.getProfiles().stream().forEach(p ->  {

              ......

              ((SingletonBeanRegistry) beanFactory).registerSingleton(profile.name, instance);
```

the problem is that the method is not been called before the controller @autowired event, so it will complain there is no StorageContext instance, I have also tried BeanFactoryPostProcessor and InitializingBean interface, neither of them works.

But, I notice if I just add some special @Bean method into the auto config class, let's say :

```
@Import(StorageContextProperties.class)
public class StorageAutoConfiguration implements BeanFactoryAware{

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor validationPostProcessor2() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }
    

    ......

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory factory) throws BeansException {
```

then the setBeanFactory() will be called before the controller, it seems that spring needs MethodValidationPostProcessor instance, so it created shared instance of singleton bean: StorageAutoConfiguration, also create StorageContextProperties instance and call setBeanFactory().

the code works if I add above @Bean method. well things also goes well in this way, but I don't like the style since I actually have no need for MethodValidationPostProcessor.

is there any elegant(without @Bean method) way to achieve it?

my requirements are :

before the controller creating event.

1 create StorageContextProperties  ( it's a @ConfigurationProperties class by @Import)
2 some callback I can call registerSingleton() to create my Storage Context instances

Thanks!

[UPDATED1]

I still don't find any way to make it works, but I changed the code as :

```
@Configuration
@Import(StorageContextProperties.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "avalon.thiton.storage.config", name = "masterKey")
public class StorageAutoConfiguration implements BeanFactoryAware {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StorageAutoConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(MethodValidationPostProcessor.class)
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor placeholder() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }

    ......
```

It makes me feel..... better.

Comment: Is StorageAutoConfiguration annotated with <at>Configuration (and referenced by the main class).  I'm suspicious that it is not, and that may cause Spring to overlook it and instantiate it late.  Plausibly, adding <at>Bean inside the class allows spring to realize it is configuration and thus initiate it early.  Just a theory, but might explain your behavior difference.

Comment: @Jeff Bennett:  thanks for your suggestion, there is a <at>Configuration with the class,   please see the UPDATE. actually, if I just add other <at>Bean method but not MethodValidationPostProcessor, it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've had similar problem when I was trying to initialize custom beans using BeanFactoryAware interface - The @Configuration annotated class was like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SomeProps.class)
class MyConfiguration implements BeanFactoryAware {

  @Override
  public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    ...
    ...
  }

  @Bean
  MyBean myBean(){
    return new MyBean();
  }
}
```

It did not run this configuration class code before MyBean was needed and NoSuchBeanDefinitionException were thrown.

To fix this I've changed BeanFactoryAware interface to extending AbstractBeanFactoryAwareAdvisingPostProcessor like that:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SomeProps.class)
class MyConfiguration extends AbstractBeanFactoryAwareAdvisingPostProcessor {

  @Override
  public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    ...
    ...
  }

  @Bean
  MyBean myBean(){
    return new MyBean();
  }
}
```